# iOS 13 AirPrint issues: can print once to a UIPrinter, subsequently get console errors like Print-Job failed: Printer not found

Tags: printing, ios13, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I've been fighting iOS 13 printing issues in my apps for over a month now.

Printing is done without the user repeatedly having to select a printer, by using `UIPrintInteractionController.printToPrinter()`

Originally, I was retaining the `UIPrinter` objects and using them repeatedly, but only after calling `contactPrinter` on them and getting a successful result. This worked fine in iOS 12 and prior.

In iOS 13, printing to the same `UIPrinter` instance more than once almost never succeeds. It will succeed if I print to it very quickly, but a minute later it will not succeed anymore. Also, it seems that `contactPrinter` often fails for no reason. The workaround was to ditch `contactPrinter` altogether, and recreate the `UIPrinter` object every time a print is needed by using the url.

OK, but doing that broke 3rd-party print servers: the above workaround is what *fixes* real AirPrint printers ie. from Canon or whoever, but, that workaround *breaks* 3rd-party AirPrint print servers like OPrint or Printopia or others -- they then error out with every print, error is that the printer cannot be contacted.

Has anyone else hit this? Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Having same issue, opened support ticket with apple developer with no response for 2 weeks!

Comment: Hey guys. Any updates on that? How did you solve the issue? Thanks

Comment: @1nstinct it's an iOS bug that got fixed "later on". I don't see it on iOS 14+.